# How to Mock Command Object that is inside Controller

Tags: grails, groovy, junit, controller, jmock

I have a controller class, inside of which i have a command object. I have a method find() which uses this command object as follows:

```
class itemController{

    //command object
    class SearchCommand{
        String email
        static constraints={
            email blank:false,email:true
        }

def find = {SearchCommand sc ->
    if(!sc.hasErrors()){
     ----- do something---
}

}
```

Now, I am writing a test case to test the find method in the controller. But the test case fails at

```
  if(!sc.hasErrors())
```

as sc is still 'null'. I am not sure how to handle this inner class command object in the test case.
The test case that i have written so far is:

```
class itemControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {

    void testFind(){
    def model = controller.find()
    assertNotNull(model)
    }
}
```

How do I handle the inner class Command Object in the test case. Do I mock it? I have tried using mockCommandObject(?), but not sure how should i pass the inner class command object to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mockCommandObject

### Class RioController

```
class RioController {
    class UserCommand{
        String email
        static constraints = {
            email blank: false, email: true
        }
    }

    def load={UserCommand cmd -> 
        if(cmd.validate()){
            flash.message = "Ok"
        }
        else{
            flash.message = "Where is the email?"
        }
    }
}
```

### Class RioControllerTests

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

@TestFor(RioController)
class RioControllerTests {

    @Test
    void testLoad(){
        mockCommandObject RioController.UserCommand
        controller.load()
        assert flash.message == "Where is the email?"

        params.email = "verynew@email.com"
        controller.load()
        assert flash.message == "Ok"
    }
}
```

Comment: Throws error at the line 'mockCommandObject SearchCommand'. It is not able to find SearchCommand. As SearchCommand is inside the itemController, how should I access it in the testCase?

Comment: You can put SearchCommand class out ItemController class, in same file but like 'external' class.

Comment: that is not possible now. The controller works perfectly fine and is in production. I cannot change the command object to make the test case work

Comment: tried mockCommandObject itemController.SearchCommand also...did not work

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: testingproject.RioControllerTests.mockCommandObject() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class testingproject.RioController$UserCommand]

Comment: Are you running Grails 2.x or 1.3.x?

Comment: Then you need change test code to class RioControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTest{...

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Closure
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:327)

Comment: Remove import grails.test.mixin.*
and @TestFor lines

Comment: the above is the error this time when i extend my test case to use ControllerUnitTestCase