# Mocking an inner class in groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit, controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Mock Command Object that is inside Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112415/how-to-mock-command-object-that-is-inside-controller)

I have a controller class, inside of which i have a command object. I have a method find() which uses this command object as follows:

```
class RexController{

    //command object
    class SearchCommand{
        String email
        static constraints={
            email blank:false,email:true
        }

def find = {SearchCommand sc ->
    if(!sc.hasErrors()){
     ----- do something---
}

}
```

Now, I am writing a test case to test the find method in the controller. But the test case fails at

```
  if(!sc.hasErrors())
```

as sc is still 'null'. I am not sure how to handle this inner class command object in the test case.
The test case that i have written so far is:

```
class itemControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {

    void testFind(){
    def model = controller.find()
    assertNotNull(model)
    }
}
```

How do I handle the inner class Command Object in the test case. Do I mock it? I have tried using mockCommandObject(?), but not sure how should i pass the inner class command object to this?

Should i be changing any meta class properties for controller in the test case so that it recognizes the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

You create/mock and pass the Command instance to your controller call in a test.

```
void testFind() {
    def command = new RexController.SearchCommand(email: 'me@here.there')
    // or [email: 'me@here.there'] as RexController.SearchCommand
    def model = controller.find(command)
    assertNotNull(model)
}
```

`mockCommandObject` [no longer exists](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails): *"The mockCommandObject() method is no longer needed as Grails automatically detects whether an action requires a command object or not."*

But you'd better move all the non-UI-related logic somewhere else - to a domain class or a service, and test that class.

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried with the code in your post. groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.RexControllerTests.mockCommand() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class com.RexController$SearchCommand]

Comment: Ops, I got mislead by some old maillist post. `mockCommand()` was a `mockCommandObject()` and is no longer needed. Updating answer.